# Нормализация базы данных списка покупок

Tags: sql, база-данных

Имеется база данных, в которой хранится список покупок пользователя. В ней имеются две таблицы Type_product и Product. В первой таблице хранятся просто названия продуктов, например - йогурт, сок и пр., а во второй их названия, данные производителем, например йогурт "Danone" или сок "Добрый".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако есть одно но - йогурт может быть клубничный или персиковый, как и сок яблочный или ананасовый. В данный момент их вкусовые характеристики прописываются в названии. Но нужно ли выделять их в отдельную таблицу-справочник, и если да, то как это сделать? Поскольку приведенными в примерах продуктами таблицы не ограничиваются, то в них могут хранится множество характеристик, характерных только для конкретных продуктов.

Comment: Нужно их выделять или нет - это надо у вас спросить. Все же зависит от назначения базы данных. От того, что происходит по технологии с этими продуктами и записями о них. Может достаточно оставить как есть и сделать над типами еще типы типов продуктов где будут большие группы, типа "йогурты". Или может справочник типов сделать древовидным.

Comment: В принципе то, что сейчас имеется меня устраивает: пользователь видит полное название покупки, например, клубничный йогурт Danone, а нужный продукт может найти через поиск, который ищет по всем входящим в название словам. Однако это меня интересует потому, что я не знаю как это выглядит с точки зрения нормализации - нарушена она или нет?

Comment: Ну так нормализация зависит от поставленных задач. Если вам например надо будет сравнить годовые продажи всего клубничного с продажами всего вишневого - то тогда конечно данная характеристика продукта становится значимой и ее придется выделять в отдельную сущность. Ну или если надо будет посчитать количество прилагательных в названиях продуктов - то придется как то разбивать названия на части речи.